# PresentViewController is showing nil of my RootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So let me explain.
I have two ViewControllers (Login-Page and Main-Page).
Login page contains two buttons (FB and G+ login buttons).
Everything works fine with login credentials and is presenting the next view which is Main-Page. 
In Main-Page I have button (sign-out).Button should work as singing out and bring me back to Login-Page, unfortunately is not working.
Below is my code

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginPage") as! LoginPage
            vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is showing

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and the output is nil for all declared IBOutlet in Main-Page

Please I need help!!!??

Comment: Double check the storyboard ID of your login view controller. It must match "LoginPage" exactly, case, no spaces. Also, it must be in the same storyboard.

Comment: no typo issue...other thing is that when I change code with : let LoginControllerx = LoginPage()
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginControllerx) it shows IBOutlet nil of LoginPage :(

Comment: @EdisShabixhiza one possible issue is you have some outlet that is not connected.

Comment: @i6x86 I have double checked and my outlet are connected, but thanks for quick response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we verify if the view controller has a `Storyboard ID` on the `Identity inspector`:

[image]

Then:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let loginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginPage")

let window = UIApplication.shared.windows[0] as UIWindow

UIView.transition(with: window,
                  duration: 0.5,
                  options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve,
                  animations: {
                       window.rootViewController = loginViewController
        }, completion: nil)
```

With that, you are replacing the presented view controller for your login view controller.

Comment: @pablerios god send you :)

Comment: Hi @EdisShabixhiza if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using notifications to change the root when you did logout for the app.

First in your appDelegate addObserver:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Notification used in logout action
    let notf = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    notf.addObserverForName("logout", object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (notification) in
       let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginPage") as! LoginPage
       self.window?.rootViewController = controller
    }
    return true
}
```

then in the logoutAction simply postNotification

```
func logout() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("logout", object: nil)
}
```

Comment: I will try this option also :) , let you know for results